# Create an ID based on similar strings

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pretty ugly dataset that has a column of random words and names. Some of these names are similar and some are not. For now, what I want to do is create a new column that would assign an ID to each name if it contains a value in another row. Though later I will have to look at actual word similarities and not just the same values.

Therefore, given:

```
     Names           
0    James            
1    James 2          
2    Bike             
3    Bicycle          
4    James Marsh      
5    Ants             
6    Job              
7    Michael          
8    Arm              
9    Mike K           
10   Michael k
```

The new column `ID` would assign the same number to every similar value so that everything similar would be grouped and every group, which could contain 1 to n `Names` would have a unique ID. The output would therefore be:

```
     Names           ID
0    James            1
1    James 2          1 #James 2 contains James, so it would be counted in the same group
2    Bike             2 #The similarity between this and Bicycle can be ignored for now
3    Bicycle          3
4    James Marsh      1 #Contains James so it's in the same group
5    Ants             4
6    Job              5
7    Michael          6
8    Arm              7
9    Mike K           8 #The similarity between this and Michael can be ignored for now
10   Michael k        6
```

I am certain there is a way to do this with `df.apply()`, I am just not sure what.

Comment: This seems to be a job for `groupby`, using a key that represents your logic for similarity.  For instance, `Names.split()[0]` would cover what you've shown so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This basically `factorize` on the first word:

```
df['ID'] = df.Names.str.extract('^(\S+)')[0].factorize()[0] + 1
```

Output:

```
          Names  ID
0         James   1
1       James 2   1
2          Bike   2
3       Bicycle   3
4   James Marsh   1
5          Ants   4
6           Job   5
7       Michael   6
8           Arm   7
9        Mike K   8
10    Michael k   6
```

**Note:** This would not match `Jame` and `James`.

Comment: So how would I match `Jame` to `James`?